# Requiring parent directive inside accordion-heading from ui bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a directive that requires a parent formController.
This directive is applied to a input element which is inside an accordion-heading (using angular ui bootstrap) and it is not able to find the parent formController. 
However if the same element is placed in the content section of accordion , it is able to access the parent formController.

I have made a sample plunkr showing the problem.
There are 2 input fields with the directive formid which requires formController. The one with class="working" is able to get parent controller, while the one with class="notworking" is not able to get the parent controller and angularjs shows an error.

http://plnkr.co/edit/azZY0rndzFUhnanjeGuq

```
 <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<form name="myForm">
  <accordion class="claimheads"> 
  <accordion-group> 
  <accordion-heading><input class="notworking" type="text" formid=""></input></accordion-heading>
           <div class="working" ng-include="'temp.html'"></div>
        </accordion-group>
        </accordion>
</form>
```

Can anyone please help me understand this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the accordion-heading directive uses transclusion. (see [here](http://blog.dudak.me/2014/angular-js-directive-communication-guide-part-2/))

You could access the form controller over the scope hierarchy by its name:

```
app.directive('formid',function(){
  return {
      // restrict to attribute
      restrict: 'A',
      require: "?^form", 
      link: function(scope, $element, $attrs, reqattrs) {

        console.log("requested:");
        console.log(reqattrs);;

        console.log("by name:"); 
        console.log(scope.$parent.$parent.myForm);

      }
  }
})
```

But this is some sort of a hack. I'm sure there's a better solution.

Comment: yea even i thought of this hack. I need a generalized solution though as the directive will be used at a lot of places. I just need the form name. How about travesrsing the DOM tree using jqLite or jQuery in the directive to get the form name? What do you think about that? again not the correct way . but might work in all cases.